# kops can't update aws cluster. RequestTimeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, kubernetes, kops

I have an issue with k8s cluster on aws.
I tried to create cluster on aws.
The first step was creation:

```
kops create cluster --name=kubernetes.xarva.stream --state=s3://kops-bucket-pnz-se-kube1 --node-count=2 --node-size=t2.micro --master-size=t2.micro --dns-zone=kubernetes.xarva.stream --zones=eu-central-1a
```

and it was successfully completed. But when I tried to update the cluster with the command:

```
kops update cluster kubernetes.xarva.stream --state=s3://kops-b                                                                                        ucket-pnz-se-kube1 --yes
```

I got this error:

```
error writing completed cluster spec: error writing configuration file s3://kops                                                                                        -bucket-pnz-se-kube1/kubernetes.xarva.stream/cluster.spec: error writing s3://ko                                                                                        ps-bucket-pnz-se-kube1/kubernetes.xarva.stream/cluster.spec: RequestTimeout: You                                                                                        r socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the tim                                                                                        eout period. Idle connections will be closed.
    status code: 400, request id: 2***********3, host id: *********************************************6
```

On the s3 bucket I found the configuration, so seems that it's read issue.
Does anybody face with this problem? Any ideas how to solve it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> RequestTimeout: Your socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections will be closed.

This error says you have a problem with access to AWS S3 from a place where you have installed kops.
Make sure you have access to S3 and try again or try to do this from another place.

Comment: Yep. Seems that you right, because it works via VPN. But I don't get why a have an access via Web (without vpn)?